# WCF REST Streaming Keep Alive Connection

Tags: wcf, http, streaming

I want to create something similar to the Twitter streaming API using WCF.  We need to stream data to clients as quickly as possible (1/4 second).  Our clients are diverse (JAVA, C++, etc. etc. etc.) and we're a .NET shop.  Does anyone know if WCF can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Streaming Data section here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

I haven't tested this but here's an example http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2009/01/streaming-media-content-over-wcf.html